# Make full page image responsive without using body tag

Tags: css, image

I've been searching up how to make an image scale up to full page, but without using the `body` tag - because if I use that tag, when I put other text and other objects, all of those text, buttons, etc. will show up on the image, instead of below it, which isn't really nice...

But so far I haven't been able to find out a solution for this, so any help / advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean 'full page'? If so, how is that not related to the body element? Do you perhaps mean 'viewport'?

Comment: @AHaworth by "full page", I mean for the banner when you first load the site. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I guess you could do something like this to alter the HTML tag, this may not be the best practice.

This is an example of the code:

```
<html style = "background-color: red;"></html>
```

Hope this helped.

Another way to do it is just adding a div, once again not the best practice but it would work.

```
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #FF0000;">&nbsp</div>
```

One of the downsides to using a div for this problem is that everything can get blocked out.